# How do i check if the snake is collidiing with the border?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I'm making a snake game in pygame and can't figure out how to do collision chek on the border of the game. I would like to implement a collision check with the border so i can end the game when the snake hits the border. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. Here is my code if it helps.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.init()

win_width, win_height = 900, 1000

game_width, game_height = 800, 800
GRID_SIZE = 40


UP = (0, -1)
DOWN = (0, 1)
LEFT = (-1, 0)
RIGHT = (1, 0)

win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height), pygame.RESIZABLE)


class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [(game_width // 2 + 50, game_height // 2 + 50)]
        self.direction = random.choice([UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT])
        self.color = (0, 255, 0)

    def get_head_position(self):
        return self.positions[0]

    def update(self):
        head = self.get_head_position()
        x, y = self.direction
        new = (((head[0] + (x * GRID_SIZE)) % game_width), (head[1] + (y * GRID_SIZE)) % game_height)
        if len(self.positions) > 2 and new in self.positions[2:]:
            self.reset()
        else:
            self.positions.insert(0, new)
            if len(self.positions) > self.length:
                self.positions.pop()

    def reset(self):
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [(game_width, game_height)]
        self.direction = random.choice([UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT])
        game_over_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Assets/Sounds/game_over.ogg")
        game_over_sound.play()

    def render(self, surface):
        for p in self.positions:
            snake_rect = pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (p[0], p[1], GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE))
            snake_up = pygame.image.load("Assets/Images/snake_up.png")
            snake_down = pygame.image.load("Assets/Images/snake_down.png")
            snake_left = pygame.image.load("Assets/Images/snake_left.png")
            snake_right = pygame.image.load("Assets/Images/snake_right.png")
            if self.direction == UP:
                surface.blit(snake_up, snake_rect)
            if self.direction == DOWN:
                surface.blit(snake_down, snake_rect)
            if self.direction == LEFT:
                surface.blit(snake_left, snake_rect)
            if self.direction == RIGHT:
                surface.blit(snake_right, snake_rect)


class Food:
    pass


def main():

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 10

    bg = pygame.image.load("Assets/Images/background.png")

    snake = Snake()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and not snake.direction == DOWN:
                    snake.direction = UP
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and not snake.direction == UP:
                    snake.direction = DOWN
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and not snake.direction == RIGHT:
                    snake.direction = LEFT
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and not snake.direction == LEFT:
                    snake.direction = RIGHT
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()

        win.fill((255, 210, 190))
        win.blit(bg, (50, 50))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (100, 100, 100), (30, 30, 840, 840), width=20)
        snake.update()
        snake.render(win)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have alredy tried "pygame.Rect.colliderect(Rect)" but can't get it to work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can modify the update method in your Snake class. After calculating the new head position (new), check if it goes beyond the game borders. I

```
def update(self):
    head = self.get_head_position()
    x, y = self.direction
    new = (((head[0] + (x * GRID_SIZE)) % game_width), (head[1] + (y * GRID_SIZE)) % game_height)

    # Check if the new head position is outside the game borders
    if new[0] < 30 or new[0] >= game_width + 30 or new[1] < 30 or new[1] >= game_height + 30:
        self.reset()
    else:
        if len(self.positions) > 2 and new in self.positions[2:]:
            self.reset()
        else:
            self.positions.insert(0, new)
            if len(self.positions) > self.length:
                self.positions.pop()
```